# NFC - Securing tag content

Tags: security, nfc

I am working on project where NFC tags have key role. I am installing tags on some sort of documents and will write ID number of this document there. Then these documents will be distributed to owners. Content of these documents are in DB and only after reading tag (doc ID) (at service centers) content will be shown.

Is there any way to protect content from being copied or read on other devices like android/any PC software to avoid creating similar tags?

Will only locking write permission and password protection solve my problem? If yes, will it be possible to first lock and then password protect tag (for owners to choose their own password)?